# FPDF- How to give auto incremented serial numbers in a column?

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to add an auto incremented serial number column in my pdf. I tried to get it from database, but since the data retrieved is random, the serial number printed on the pdf is random as well. I want to start it like 1, 2, 3...

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `" . $DB->pre . "order_detail` 
        WHERE orderID= '$orderID'"; 
$rows2 = $DB->dbRows($sql2);

if ($DB->numRows > 0){

    $pdf->SetLineWidth(0);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $newL=110;         ////fixed cell spaced in y-axis for quantity
    $cnt=0;
    foreach ($rows2 as $d2) {
        $rows2++;
        $pdf->SetXY(11,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(11,7, ,1,0,'L',0); /////SERIAL NUMBER COLUMN/////
        $pdf->SetXY(22,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(22,7,$d2['materialDesc'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(44,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(15,7,$d2['chart'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(59,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(25,7,$d2['shade'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(84,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(18,7,$d2['materialSize'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(102,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(25,7,$d2['quantity'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(127,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(15,7,'ROL',1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(142,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(18,7,'OPEN',1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(160,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(35,7,$d2['remarks'],1,0,'L',0);
        $newL += 7;  
    }     
}
$pdf-> Ln();
```

Comment: The idea at SO is that YOU code something. If you get issues with it, you ask us for help. We do not write your code for you

Comment: Duh.. I'm using FPDF for the first time and I couldn't find any help from any other sites. All I asked was for an idea and not to write the entire code. You better flush your ego mate.

Comment: Is this serial number the same on all lines of this report, or +1 on each line of this report. Do you need this serial number to be remembered so that on your next report it can be oldserial+1 on every line. or will you start from 1 on every report

Comment: plus 1 on each line and starts from 1 on every report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then all you need is a counter.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `" . $DB->pre . "order_detail` 
        WHERE orderID= '$orderID'"; 
$rows2 = $DB->dbRows($sql2);

if ($DB->numRows > 0){

    $pdf->SetLineWidth(0);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $newL=110;         ////fixed cell spaced in y-axis for quantity

    // you already had a counter so I am reusing it
    $cnt=1;

    foreach ($rows2 as $d2) {
        $rows2++;
        $pdf->SetXY(11,$newL);

        // place counter in column
        $pdf->Cell(11,7, $cnt,1,0,'L',0); /////SERIAL NUMBER COLUMN/////
        $pdf->SetXY(22,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(22,7,$d2['materialDesc'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(44,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(15,7,$d2['chart'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(59,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(25,7,$d2['shade'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(84,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(18,7,$d2['materialSize'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(102,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(25,7,$d2['quantity'],1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(127,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(15,7,'ROL',1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(142,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(18,7,'OPEN',1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->SetXY(160,$newL);
        $pdf->Cell(35,7,$d2['remarks'],1,0,'L',0);
        $newL += 7;  
        // add 1 to the counter
        $cnt++;
    }     
}
$pdf-> Ln();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. Cheers.